# Change an answer from "downgrade ..." to "update to version x of tool"

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently saw some answers in the review queue where someone changed an answer from

"Downgrade to version xxx of tool x will help" (which was accepted) to "Update to version xxx of tool x, they uploaded a new version with fix"

The edit got rejected several times by reason "invalid edit".

Example: [AWS Beanstalk cli-tool configuration validation exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763177/aws-beanstalk-cli-tool-configuration-validation-exception/17822690#17822690)

> [image]

What's the best solution on this -

- Add the edit as a new answer?
- Edit the answer but append new version notice instead of replacing?

Comment: I would leave the first sentence intact and just change "Try going back to 2.4" to be "Upgrade to 2.5.1 where it's fixed".

Comment: Changing the answer like that is a major change and could potentially change it from an answer that worked for the OP to one that does not.

Answer (score 13):

I would prefer to see updates like this as a new answer.

If I am suggesting a version X that I know works, I would feel bad seeing version Y, unknown to me, as a suggestion signed with my name.

As a reader, I would prefer to see both working solutions in case the new one does not quite work for me. And if both X and Y works, why not to have both as answers and let people vote on them to see which one solves OPs problem better?

Comment: Fair point but the original text is "**Try** going back to" meaning the author is not sure that would work either.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well, is it a question about updating versions or about low quality original that maybe should be a comment and certainly should use more research? I assumed first in my answer. In the second case it should be resolved in the comments first, edited later IMO.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Or the original author is not as semantically conscious as you are. I would say that this edit should be a new answer, perhaps after pinging the original author to hear if (s)he would change it. Or, as it is now, where both informations are available in the same answer, turning it into a de facto CW.

Comment: @AndersUP and Molot, OK, agree it's best to let the original author edit by leaving a comment. But posting whole new answer just for that doesn't seem right to me for some reason.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd if answer is not a quite an answer, then fixing it should be a priority. But there is a fine line between fixing and radical changes, and I think it was crossed here. If that would be original answerer to make this edit, after clarifying things in comments - great. 3rd party edit? Not so.

Comment: @Mołot thin line in my opinion, after all edits should also improve existing content and make it better/correct.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd the same discussion was repeated many many times about editing code in answers. Substituting code with library versions and repeating it all over seems pointless to me.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "Whole new answer doesn't seem right"... I'm going to give you my prime example, which I've used before, of why suggested edits are particularly broken for answers. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15611256/806549) answer, that I had to make after seeing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1778349#./1778349?&_suid=1381836612867025440195098648854) rejected for a) making the variable names in the answer identical to the question and b) including one line from the question in the answer, as the OP didn't know where the code belonged.

Comment: Changing an answer from suggesting a downgrade to an earlier version that versus upgrading to a new version which may or may not have other compatibility problems.